# Does the Linux kernel IPv6 NAT ?

Tags: linux-kernel

Does the Linux kernel IPv6 NAT ?

I know linux kernel was not supposed to support IPv6 NAT.

But I  am curious know , is there any Linux kernel which supports IPv6 NAT.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are multiple [guides](https://mirrors.bieringer.de/Linux+IPv6-HOWTO/nat-netfilter6..html) on the net on how to setup ipv6 NAT on linux.

> Does the linux kernel **support** the IPv6 NAT?

Yes it does. Have you even checked [Google](https://www.google.pl/search?q=ipv6+nat+linux) ?

> I know linux kernel was not supposed to support IPv6 NAT.

No, this statement is wrong. Linux kernel is supposed to support IPv6 network address translation.

> Is there any Linux kernel which support Ipv6 NAT?

Any linux kernel with version greater then 3.9.0 and iptables utility greater then 1.4.18 supports ipv6 NAT (from [here](https://mirrors.bieringer.de/Linux+IPv6-HOWTO/nat-netfilter6..html)). So there are plenty linux kernels with that support.